# Tap input / Magnetic input not working on android unity cardboard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Is there any reason tap input is not getting through to a Google Cardboard App made with Unity for Android? Works in the editor, as a mouse click. In the cardboard script settings 'Tap is Trigger' is ticked. 
Also cannot get magnetic input, am using the method from here: [www.andrewnoske.com](http://www.andrewnoske.com/wiki/Unity_-_Detecting_Google_Cardboard_Click)

Comment: Not nearly enough information to answer the question.

Comment: what other info would you want?

Comment: Check the description of `unity` tag. If this is about unity the game engine change the tag to `unity3d`. Also post the code related to the problem. How are you trying to detect tap inputs?

Comment: I don't mean to doubt the content in your link, but is there a reason you're using it instead of the Cardboard SDK for Unity?

Comment: I'm using the cardboard sdk! - is there a way to get the magnet input?

Answer (score 2):

ok turns out it is hidden in the cardboard sdk. if you do something like:

> void Update () {
>
> ```
>   if (Cardboard.SDK.CardboardTriggered) {     
>   //something here;
> ```
>
> }

that should do it...